Posting and monitoring build metric from Azure pipeline to Azure DevOps
I have a following use case:
Firmware for a microcontroller is build in Azure pipeline, I would like to monitor ROM and RAM memory usage (basically two numbers) on each build and be able to monitor overall trend from a chart somewhere in Azure DevOps (some dashboard probably). I can write a script to extract this data after build, but how to make it available in Azure DevOps?
What have I considered:

During build exporting required information to a file (JSON probably) and storing it as an artefact. Then posting it somehow to Azure DevOps (but where and how to post? What is the proper way to do it in Azure?)
Azure Pipelines has possibility to read test result format generated by CTest and publish them to Azure DevOps, so it might be possible to make somehow a custom Measuring test with CTest, but would Azure Pipelines/DevOps handle it properly and is it a right way to go?

Any other proposals are welcome!
Edit: Of course this would only be done for main protected branch, not every pipeline run.
Also, the pipeline builds different firmware configurations, each needs to be evaluated separately

Maybe try to find a way to write the data (ROM and RAM memory usage) to a Log Analytics Workspace? You can create dashboards and even configure alerts based on the data, if needed.

Can you clarify your requirements? Do you want to display this chart information in Azure resources or Azure DevOps itself? Azure and Azure DevOps are slightly different and there is a bit of confusion in your description.

Kevin, I am sorry for confusion, I'm only starting to get familliar with Azure family of services. I would prefer to see this chart in Azure Devops, probably on some dashboard. Everywhere that I've mentioned Azure, I wanted to say Azure DevOps. Though, maybe other services are better for this task, I know there is Azure Monitor and etc. But the final goal would be to see chart in Azure DevOps dashboard

Rui, thank you for proposal. I will review the documentation on Log Analytics Workspace now

The Log Analytics seem like a workaround meant for monitoring Azure services. I think there suppose to be a more proper space to hold this data, I'm sure I'm not the only one who want to monitor some application metrics

@DanielBeliavskij I am afraid that there is no built-in Dashboard widget or Extension Dashboard widget can record and monitoring the build metric. I have shared a workaround in the answer for you to refer to. I also suggest that you can create a suggestion ticket to report this feature.

Measuring RAM usage of a MCU at compile-time is not trivial. Apart from the allocated RAM, the stack is dynamic and stack usage depends on complex things like call stack depth together with (nested) interrupt depth, in addition to the stack usage for variables. Before you worry about the DevOps fluff, maybe outline how you plan to measure RAM use in the first place?

Well, RAM usage is not the main concern, for now we are simply extracting this data from linker and it's enough to see the allocated RAM size. The main concern is to monitor the flash usage. Which is also provided by the linker output

I am afraid that there is no built-in Dashboard widget or Extension Dashboard widget can record and monitoring the build metric.
We can use other Azure Services(e.g. Azure Monitor) or tools(PowerBI) to record data and generate reports, but they cannot be displayed in the Azure DevOps Dashboard.
For a workaround, I suggest that you can use Azure DevOps Work item to record the ROM and RAM data and then you can use query to filter the work items to generate chart.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create a New Worm item type in Organization Settings -> Processes and add custom fields(e.g. ROM and RAM) to the new work item type.
Step2: When you running the Pipeline, you can create a new work item for each build(use Rest API: Create work item or extension: Create work item ) and set the value to the work item field.
For example:

Step3: Create and run the Query in Boards -> Queries to filter related work items and set the fields in the query column.
for example:

Step4: You can create the chart in Query/Dashboard based on the query result. Refer to this doc: Example query charts
For example:

Since this is a workaround, it will have limitations.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.
Hope there will be an official Dashboard widget in the future that can directly implement this function.
